# NLog with AzureTableStorage

Tags: azure, nlog, azure-table-storage

Trying to insert logs into Azure table storage, while using the extension of NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage in Nlog.config file , i am getting error under target type for azure table storage.

Error : - **This is invalid xsi:type http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:AzureTableStorage**

FYI - I am using latest version Nlog latest version 4.4.11 & i added extension of Nlog.extensions.azuretablestorage(Nuget version 1.1.4)

**Update for config file:**

```html
<extensions> 
  <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage"/> 
</extensions> 
<!-- set up a an azure storage table target --> 
<targets>
  <target name="AzureTableStorage" xsi:type="AzureTableStorage" PartitionKey="${date}.${logger}" RowKey="${ticks}.${guid}" ConnectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" tableName="TempAzureTableStorageTargetTestsLogs" /> 
</targets>
```

Comment: Not enough details.

Comment: <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- set up a an azure storage table target -->
  <targets>
    <target name="AzureTableStorage"
        xsi:type="AzureTableStorage"
        PartitionKey="${date}.${logger}"
        RowKey="${ticks}.${guid}"
        ConnectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
        tableName="TempAzureTableStorageTargetTestsLogs" />
  </targets>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> This is invalid xsi:type http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:AzureTableStorage

I assumed that you have installed [NLog.Config](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config/) that would automatically create the default `NLog.config`. Since this package references [NLog.Schema](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema/) which would enable Intellisense(TM) when editing NLog configuration files.

I have checked with this issue, the above message is just for warning, the logging feature would be fine. And you could remove the NLog.Config and NLog.Config packages, then the warning message would go away.

> FYI - I am using latest version Nlog latest version 4.4.11 & i added extension of Nlog.extensions.azuretablestorage(Nuget version 1.1.4)

AFAIK, the latest version for [NLog Azure Table Storage Target](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureTableStorageNLogTarget/) is 1.0.11. Here is my code snippet, you could refer to it:

**NLog.config**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage"/>
  </extensions>
  
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="AzureTableStorage" 
            name="NLogAzureTable"
            ConnectionStringKey="NLog.Azure.TableStorage.ConnectionString" 
            TableName="NLogTable"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="NLogAzureTable" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**App.config**

```html
<appSettings>
  <add key="NLog.Azure.TableStorage.ConnectionString" value="{your-storage-account-connectionString}" />
</appSettings>
```

**Usage:**

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(nameof(Program));
logger.Info("hello world!!!");
```

**Result:**

[image]

For more details about how to configure the NLog Azure Table Storage Target, you could refer to [NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage](https://github.com/harouny/NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage). Also, you could refer to [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial) for more tutorials.